# How to setup device mapper RAID on LVM on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, raid, lvm

I have read that LVM can be setup as raid without using mdadm. I have setup LVM with two physical HDD and would like to set up RAID1 but I can't find any guidance.

Is there any documentation on how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Device-mapper#RAID1

Though I don't think you can boot off it and the management tools are pretty low level. If you can't manage it well then RAID just becomes a great way to lose your data :) It's nowhere near as convenient as using MD to create a RAID and then adding that MD block device as physical volume to a LVM volume group.

Comment: @Hani, Check out the following link to create fake block devices so you can test all this out without messing with your disks. http://askubuntu.com/questions/546921/how-to-create-virtual-block-devices/546922#546922